# add "active "class to the selected list item through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class name "active" which i want to be added to the selected list item.

Here is how my list style looks like:

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">

<li class="start active">
                    <a href="dashboard.php"><span class="title">Dashboard</span></a>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Pages</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li >
                            <a href="all-pages.php">All Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li >
                            <a href="add-page.php">Add Page</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

              <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Posts</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li >
                            <a href="all-posts.php">All Posts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li >
                            <a href="add-posts.php">Add Posts</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

</ul>
```

i want to add class on two places one is "li" under sub-menu and `<span class="title">Posts</span>`

It should look something like this
[image]

I tried something like this but didnt work

```
$('.page-sidebar-menu ul li a').click(function() {
              $('.page-sidebar-menu ul li').removeClass('active');    
              $(this).addClass('active');
            });
```

Please suggest some solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".sub-menu li").addClass("active");
$(".title").addClass("active");
```

To add a class to a the list-element and the title Post element.
If you want to remove a class you can use. '.removeClass([class to be removed])'

function to do so:

```
$(".sub-menu li").click(function(){
  $(".sub-menu li").removeClass('active');//to make sure there will be only one with the class 'active'
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fg9xN/)**

Comment: Yes but i need to remove the previous class also. and need to have a class on `<span class="title">Posts</span>`

Comment: @user3201500 But the li-item has no previous class. And do you want the class 'title' to be removed too?

Comment: No i dont want to remove class 'title'.

Comment: just added a screenshot. Please consider that too. Thank you.

Comment: @user3201500: Sounds like you want to to `$(".sub-menu li.active").remnoveClass('active')` before you add the class to the other element.